# SwingWorker não entra no PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, swing

Criei um swingworker para exibir um JDialog enquanto o código fica parado aguardando o usuário coloca o dedo no leitor de impressão digital

Tudo funcionou certinho, setei como visível dentro do PropertyChangeListener e o método de colher a digital dentro do doInBackground.

O problema é que quando coloco o doInBackuground retornar um valor(que é uma string retornada pelo metodo de colher a biometria para que eu guarde no BD) aí não dispara o evento de STARTED para o PropertyChangeListener. Quando vai entrar nele já é no DONE, então o setvisible(true) do JDialog não é alcançado.

Segue abaixo o código do meu SwingWorker:

```
public class Loader extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    private JDialog dialog;


    public Loader(Frame owner) {
        dialog = new JDialog(owner, "Loading", true);
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("/opt/workspace/openbravo2/src-beans/com/openbravo/images/fingerinsert.png") );
        dialog.add( label );
        //dialog.add(progressPane);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    if (getState() == StateValue.STARTED) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (getState() == StateValue.STARTED) {
                                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } 
                } 
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return getFingerPrint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        dialog.dispose();
    }

}
```

E aqui abaixo a chamada:

```
Loader loader = new Loader(null);
loader.execute();

try {
    System.out.println(loader.get());
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Então como eu falei, se eu não colocar o trecho do get() então tudo funciona certinho, mas com ele não dispara o evento de start(que pelo que entendi é quando o doInBackground começa a executar).

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi: o que tem que ser feito em background você coloca em doinbackground, e quando for passar algum valor pra Thread principal, você passa pelo método `done();`. Veja [aqui](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/apendice-mais-swing-e-recursos-avancados/#11-6-swingworker) por exemplo.

Comment: Foi quebrado o código, não sei porque.. estou editando corrigindo. Mas em complemento a seu comentário @DiegoFelipe, o método done() retorna void, na verdade ele "retorna o retorno" da doInBackground.

Comment: Esse método getFingerPrint() vai abrir o leitor, aguardar o colhimento da digital e vai retornar uma String, que é a digital convertida pra ser armazenada no BD. Por isso ele fica no background porque tem um momento que ele "trava" a execução, que é quando ele acende a luz do leitor e aguarda até que o usuário coloque o dedo lá ou expire o tempo.